# Use Solrj in java exception

Tags: java, apache, solr

I wanna use Solrj in netbeans, I write this code:

```java
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;

import java.io.IOException;

public class SolrjPopulator {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SolrServerException {
    CommonsHttpSolrServer server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");
    for(int i=0;i<1000;++i) {
      SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
      doc.addField("cat", "book");
      doc.addField("id", "book-" + i);
      doc.addField("name", "The Legend of Po part " + i);
      server.add(doc);
      if(i%100==0) server.commit();  // periodically flush
    }
    server.commit(); 
  }
}
```

When I run example I get this exeption:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpConnectionManager
```

Why my code didn't work? What I have to do?

Comment: Look like you're missing `commons-httpclient.jar` from your classpath.

Comment: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/runerrormessages.html#NOCLASSDEFFOUNDERROR

Comment: i add this jar, but i get again same exception :(

Comment: Which version of Solr are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Add the missing library to your classpath that you use to execute your application. [jar-finder has some libraries that contain this class](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnectionManager), it's probably commons-httpclient.